# How would you best configure JSS to work with multiple Sitecore <sites>?

Tags: jss

One of the key benefits I can see from moving to JSS is the way developers can work with the different tools. In particular the lure of Hot Module Replacement (HMR) adds such a lot of positives for development speed. Therefore its key we don't lose this capability - building the whole JSS project for every change would not be a good solution.

We have a traditional Sitecore setup which relies heavily on `<sites>`. Examples being configured as follows:

- www.domain.com <= en-ca
- www.domain.com/fr <= fr-ca
- www.anotherdomain.com <= en-au
- www.anotherdomain.com/fr and www.anotherdomain.com/fr-fr shouldn't work

In the non-jss world we are achieving the `/fr` url chunk via config in `<sites>` for the french site of: `virtualFolder="/fr" physicalFolder="/fr"`

When running in headless mode I believe this could be achieved with the configuration of express however how could this be done when doing connected, 'HMR driven development' (`jss start:connected`) as this by default always runs `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 4):

When running in connected mode, there is an Express server that runs next to your JSS app (by default at `localhost:3000`). However, your app is making requests to your Sitecore instance via whatever URL you've defined in the `layoutServiceHost` property in `scjssconfig.json`.

That means you can modify the `layoutServiceHost` property to use whatever site hostName is appropriate for the `<site />` nodes you have defined in your Sitecore instance.

If you need to modify the `layoutServiceHost` value at runtime, for instance to reflect some URL fragment or parameter, then you can do so wherever you make a call to `dataApi.fetchRouteData` (or "globally" in your app wherever you resolve routes). The JSS sample apps make that call in the `RouteHandler` component (in React and Vue), and you'll see in the `getRouteData` method of that component that it sets the `layoutServiceConfig.host` property to the `config.sitecoreApiHost` value. That value, by default, comes from `scjssconfig.json`, but as mentioned it can come from anywhere or be modified prior to usage.